# How to install Procedural Option in Oracle 11gr2

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

I've been trying to create PL/SQL packages and running procedures on a local installation of Oracle 11gR2 on my computer, and I kept getting ORA-00900 error. Based on this [article](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00900.php), it seems like Procedural Option has not been not installed.

This is the output of sqlplus when I logged in:

```
C:\Users\NgCH>sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Feb 14 13:11:34 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: system@orcl
Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

How can I install it? If I've to reinstall Oracle, what are the options I must choose in the installer? I chosen Enterprise Edition, Desktop Class.

Thanks.

Edit:

This is *very* simple package code I tried to execute in DBeavor (64-bit) v2.0.6, to a local Oracle database with Oracle thin connection:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST AS

hello_world constant varchar(20) := 'hello world';

END TEST;
```

Error from DBeavor:

```
Error occurred during SQL query execution

Reason:
SQL Error [900] [42000]: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This belongs on [SuperUser,](http://superuser.com/) IMO.

Comment: I doubt that the "Procedural Option" is your problem.  I've never heard of such an option, and I can't imagine why anybody would install Oracle without PL/SQL, or why that would even be an option.  When I searched for the phrase, the first hit I found in the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/MIG73/apb.htm#b2) implies that this option was removed over 20 years ago, in version 7.1.  More likely this is a syntax error, and you need to post the relevant code.

Comment: The SQL*Plus banner in that link doesn't mention PL/SQL anyway. You can verify that you do indeed have PL/SQL installed (and I don't think it's possible to not have it, since it isn't listed as a separate component in `dba_registry` and so much internal stuff relies on it) by querying the `v$version` view. `oerr` just says 'Invalid SQL statement` back to at least 9i, though [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm) still mentioned the procedural option then; [it hasn't been listed at all since](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/toc.htm).

Comment: For future questions: you should always post the SQL you run, state the tool you use to run it and post the **exact** error message you get.

Answer (score 2):

I've followed the advice in the comments and learnt that my problem isn't with my Oracle database installation at all.

I was using DBeaver while attempting to run some pl/sql script, and for some reason I don't know it failed with the ORA-00900. After posting the question I ran the same script in Toad for Oracle, and it works without any problem. Running the same script in SQL Plus also works okay.

I don't know what causes the error in DBeaver yet, but at least now I know the error code ORA-00900 does not mean my database is missing any Procedural Option function. In hindsight I probably should have tested my script in SQL Plus first before posting the question.

Anyway, thanks for the comments guys, it really helped me tons.

Answer (score 0):

DBeaver cannot execute PL/SQL as they view it as Oracle specific, which it is. This may be implemented some time in the future.