# SQL Trigger Statement ignored

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

It should ensure that you can set only predefined values else it shows error. I get error

> Error at line 6: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   4. FOR EACH ROW
>   5. DECLARE
>   6. v_stru VARCHAR2(50);

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER radnici_strucna_sprema
 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF STRUCNA_SPREMA ON radnici
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_stru VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  v_stru := :NEW.strucna_sprema;
  IF v_ss = 'osnovno' THEN
    :NEW.strucna_sprema := v_stru;
  ELSIF v_ss = 'srednje' THEN
    :NEW.strucna_sprema := v_stru;
  ELSIF v_ss = 'vise' THEN
    :NEW.strucna_sprema := v_stru;
  ELSIF grade = 'visoko' THEN
    :NEW.strucna_sprema := v_stru;
  ELSE
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(NUM => -20002, 
            MSG => 'Forma strucne spreme nije odgovarajuca!');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Which client are you seeing that error in? It looks like [this sort of issue with your client not handling PL/SQL properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37684613/266304), but maybe a different client... Also, not directly relevant, but where are `v_ss` and `grade` supposed to be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER radnici_strucna_sprema
 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON radnici
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_stru VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  v_stru := :NEW.strucna_sprema;
  IF v_ss = 'osnovno' THEN
    :NEW.strucna_sprema := v_stru;
  ELSIF v_ss = 'srednje' THEN
    :NEW.strucna_sprema := v_stru;
  ELSIF v_ss = 'vise' THEN
    :NEW.strucna_sprema := v_stru;
  ELSIF grade = 'visoko' THEN
    :NEW.strucna_sprema := v_stru;
  ELSE
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(NUM => -20002, 
            MSG => 'Forma strucne spreme nije odgovarajuca!');
  END IF;
END;
```

The problem is

> OF STRUCNA_SPREMA.

This variable, **STRUCNA_SPREMA**, is a column in your table, **radnici**, or what is representing ?
But to be honest, I do not understand your logic. You assign the value of the column in a variable and then assign the value of that variable in your column. Why ?! Moreover, be sure that STRUCNA_SPREMA is a varchar.

Kind regards,
Stefan

Comment: The `OF STRUCNA_SPREMA` means the trigger only fires if that column is updated, so [that is valid](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_trigger.htm#BABGDFBI) (even if the logic doesn't make much sense). This doesn't explain or avoid the error the OP is gettting.

Comment: The logic is: I have predefined values for strucna_sprema and it needs to check is the value one of the predefined and if so to set that column if not to send and error